# I am having trouble connecting a MSSQL database to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, database, tiny-tds

I am attempting to connect a clients database to a rails app I am developing for them. They are using MSSQL for their database. I am able to connect to it thanks to Tiny-tds but when I run rake:db migrate I get the following message:

> TinyTds::Error: Database 'MSSQL' does not exist. Make sure that
>   the name is entered correctly.

The database does exist.

Here is what I have in my database.yml:

```
development:
    adapter: sqlserver
    host: *.*.*.*.*
    port: 1433
    database: MSSQL
    username: username
    password: not the real password
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why it doesn't recognize that the database exists?

Comment: Have you created the `MSSQL` database yet? `db:migrate` won't do that for you, that is done with `db:create`.

Comment: The client has a MSSQL database already that they have been using for years so it has all the data, tables, et cetera. I am just trying to connect to it so I can render data from their database into the web app.

Comment: I'm not talking about the database system, I'm talking about the logical database provided by the server. You are telling ActiveRecord to connect to a logical DB named 'MSSQL'.

Comment: Also, if you are connecting to a preexisting DB with data, why on earth are you running `db:migrate` as a first step?

Comment: This is my first time working with a project such as this one in which I am connecting to an outside database. I am running rake db:migrate because if I run "rails server" and go to my localhost it is giving me the error that migrations are pending.

Comment: I am a bit confused on my end but what I am getting from what you are telling me is initially I should <create:db> first with the same name as the database I am connecting too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150888/discussion-between-jermaine-subia-and-adam-lassek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `database` field in the configuration is the name of the logical database that you are connecting to. This error means that there is no logical database named 'MSSQL' for the given connection.